# Background image not loading on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a `div` which has a `background` property on it. The `background` is a `url` which loads fine on all computers and browsers, loads fine on Android but doesn't load on iPhone.

Here is the style for the `div`:

```
background: url('http://emergypower.com/assets/images/attraction.png');
background-position: center -90px;
height: 590px;
width: 100%;
```

This is custom CSS, I am not using a framework for it. Furthermore, when the user opens the "tab view" on iPhone (to see all the Safari tabs that they have open) the image displays fine, however when opened in the real browser view it does not display.

I originally did not have the width set and thought that this may have caused the problems but have since edited it and it has made no difference.

Comment: try setting `background-size:100% auto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethaan might be right but I prefer to use `background-size: 100% cover;` to ensure the image is always sizing to it's container.

Answer (score 1):

It think I might have three possible solutions. It might depend on which iOS version you’re testing on.

1. An old fix for a bug with background-image on older iOS devices was to add `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to the element.
2. Some older iOS versions has an image file size limit off 2290x2290px. Is the image to big?
3. Adding `position: relative;` and `background-repeat: no-repeat;` might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the background to this.

```
background: url("http://emergypower.com/assets/images/attraction.png");
background-size: cover
```

Answer (score 1):

add background size

```
background: url("http://emergypower.com/assets/images/attraction.png");
background-size: 100% 100%;
```